# How to get current text of select element using jquery change function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my php code which fetch dynamically records of email in select tag
I am new to php and having this issue and troubling with this from last night.

```
<select class="form-control input-md" name="leads" id="leads" class="leads">

<option value="none"  selected>-------------------------------------------Select User----------------------------------------</option>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
    if($row['activate']=='1'){?>
        <option value="<?php $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['email'];   }?></option>   
        <?php endwhile;?>                   
</select>
```

This is jquery code for change function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#leads').change(function(){
            alert($("#leads option:selected").text());
        });
    });            
</script>
```

I want to use ajax function for fetching the result from mysql database

kinldy let me know , how can i proceed further
i tried alot time and many ways but still it is not working.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/saxenxLv/  His code is working

Comment: not related but please scape your php and javascript in HTML to avoid XSS or SQL injection

Comment: is there any problem with dynamic fetching of rows as a option..Bcoz it works when options are static

Comment: sorry @Anant  i was trying to change code...But it still not working

Comment: i added jquery library

Comment: its not showing anything after var_dump($row['email']) also...was i doing anything wrong..plz suggest me @anant

Comment: @RahulTikhe  did you checked or not?

Comment: @Anant still struggling on it. but yet not success.

Comment: After using my code what id the output of `<?php var_dump($row);?>`. Also you putted `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` it in your current page on top just after opening `<?php` or not?

Comment: i applied your code but it is not showing any data type of $row. what should i do?  Even i also applied error_reporting(E_ALL) and second method of ini_set.

Comment: it means your query is not working